# Assembly Error while creating new report viewer

Tags: .net, json.net, reportviewer

Trigger By clicking Design New Report in Report Viewer

[image: Report viewer error with following error]

After I installed the latest stable 9.0.1 version of Newtonsoft.Json

I've tried uninstalling and re-install the Newtonsoft.Json but the error still there.

I can find this line in my package.config

as i do the uninstallation by selecting force uninstall and remove dependency the line will removed as well. After reinstallation that line will be there again and error still there.

Please hellllp .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put or replace the assembly file in  [ProgramFiles32]\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies. Make sure you make a copy first before you replace.